# "It makes the proof of most theorems (become) trivial" - do I need become here?

Tags: complementation

I want to say "By assuming XXX, it makes the proof of most theorems (become) trivial and less interesting"

Should I use "become" here? It looks to me both of them is ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need or even want *become* in this sentence. *Make* in constructions like *MAKE X Y* has the meaning *cause X to become Y*, so *become* is superfluous.

You also want to delete *by* and *it*, or rewrite to justify the *by*. That *by* clause wants an implicit subject who does the assuming. *It* won't work, because *it* 'stands for' the clause itself. For instance, you could write

> By assuming XXX, **we** make the proof &c

But it is much simpler to make *assuming XXX* the 'agent' which causes the proof to become trivial:

> Assuming XXX makes the proof &c